# sql obtener la ultima entrada de una tabla con valores repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, sqlite

Hola tengo una tabla con 3 entradas:

articulo color fecha_de_venta

lo que quiero es sacar una query que me diga que de que color es el ultimo articulo vendido para cada articulo

tabla_ejemplo:

| articulo | color | fecha_de_venta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mesa | verde | 2022-01-01 08:03:25.0 |
| silla | roja | 2022-01-02 08:03:25.0 |
| mesa | amarillo | 2022-01-03 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | azul | 2022-01-04 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | roja | 2022-01-05 08:03:25.0 |

lo que espero seria una salida tal que así:

| articulo | color | fecha_de_venta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| silla | roja | 2022-02-05 08:03:25.0 |
| mesa | amarillo | 2022-03-05 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | roja | 2022-01-05 08:03:25.0 |

yo he hecho esto:

```
SELECT articulo, max(fecha_de_venta)
from tabla_ejemplo
group by articulo
```

| articulo | fecha_de_venta |
| --- | --- |
| silla | 2022-01-02 08:03:25.0 |
| mesa | 2022-01-03 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | 2022-01-05 08:03:25.0 |

en el hilo he visto que la solución para una tabla que la fecha sea siempre diferente es:

```
SELECT A.articulo, A.fecha_de_venta, B.color 
from (
    select articulo, max(fecha_de_venta) as fecha_de_venta
        from test 
        group by articulo
    ) A 
inner join test B on A.fecha_de_venta = B.fecha_de_venta
```

sin embargo si la tabla inicial es:

| articulo | color | fecha_de_venta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mesa | verde | 2022-01-01 08:03:25.0 |
| silla | roja | 2022-01-02 08:03:25.0 |
| mesa | amarillo | 2022-01-04 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | azul | 2022-01-04 08:03:25.0 |
| tv | roja | 2022-01-05 08:03:25.0 |

la solución propuesta no es suficiente

Comment: Tan sólo añade `AND A.articulo = B.articulo` en la condición del JOIN.

Comment: Alex podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles y marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado, y si las otras también te ayudaron valora darles tu voto positivo también

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.articulo, t2.color, t1.Ultima_Fecha
from (select articulo, max(fecha_de_venta) as Ultima_Fecha
      from tabla_ejemplo
      group by articulo) T1 
      inner join tabla_ejemplo T2 on T1.Ultima_Fecha = T2.fecha_de_venta
```

A tu consulta original a través de la **claúsula inner join** haces una relación con ella misma por el **campo fecha_de_venta** y una vez que haces esta relación harías una consulta general que encierra a tu consulta original donde ya puedes obtener todos los campos deseados.

Para que funcione según lo nuevo que pides deberías modificar la estructura de tu tabla e incorporar un campo id y hacer todas las relaciones con este nuevo campo id en vez de con el campo fecha:

```
select t1.articulo, t2.color, t1.Ultima_Fecha
from (select articulo, max(fecha_de_venta) as Ultima_Fecha
      from tabla_ejemplo
      group by articulo) T1 
      inner join tabla_ejemplo T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```

Comment: hola @Japv 
funciona! pero me gustaria ir un paso mas (para rizar el rizo),
si se considera que se pueden vender dos objetos "diferentes" a la vez:
la tabla inicial quedaria tal que asi:

articulo|color   |fecha_de_venta       |
--------|--------|---------------------|
mesa    |verde   |2022-01-01 08:03:25.0|
silla   |roja    |2022-01-02 08:03:25.0|
mesa    |amarillo|2022-01-04 08:03:25.0|
tv      |azul    |2022-01-04 08:03:25.0|
tv      |roja    |2022-01-05 08:03:25.0|
 
entonces se repiten valores en la respuesta

te añado la tabla en la pregunta principal!

Gracias

Comment: A ver @AlexTrujillo ya esta pregunta quedo respondida y cumple con lo que originalmente pides, si quieres algo nuevo te propongo que hagas una nueva publicación y expliques ahí tu nueva problemática

Comment: Para que se resuelva tu nueva problemática debes modificar la estructura de tu tabla y incorporar un campo id, y hacer los inner join con este nuevo campo id en vez de con la fecha como lo haces originalmente

Answer (score 1):

Esta bien tu primer consulta donde obtienes la fecha máxima de cada articulo, ahora con esa fecha busca el color que corresponde a ese registro, algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
te.articulo, 
max(te.fecha_de_venta),
(select color from tabla_ejemplo where articulo = te.articulo and fecha_de_venta = max(te.fecha_de_venta)) as 'color'
from tabla_ejemplo te
group by te.articulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Una query directa en una sola consulta seria imposible. Para ello te recomiendo hacer uso de sub querys como te presentare acontinuación:

```
SELECT A.articulo, A.fecha_de_venta, B.color 
from (
    select articulo, max(fecha_de_venta) as fecha_de_venta
        from tabla_ejemplo 
        group by articulo
    ) A 
inner join tabla_ejemplo B on A.fecha_de_venta = B.fecha_de_venta
group by A.articulo;
```

Lo que hacemos es tener nuestra consulta de maximos dentro de un subquery, y después en el query principal validamos con un join y las fechas máximas de ambas consultas, y por ultimo agruparlas por el articulo.

Espero esto te sea de gran ayuda.